# ANTLR Parse with Missing Elements

Tags: parsing, kotlin, antlr4

How can ANTLR parse missing elements in a list as null (or some other placeholder value)? The following expressions should be distinguishable via the visitor interface.

```
[1,,2]
[1,2,]
[,1,2]
```

Here's an example grammar:

```
grammar Test;

list : '[' elems+=number? (',' elems+=number?)* ']';

number : DIGIT+;
DIGIT: [0-9];
```

And here's a test program written in Kotlin:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(doTest("[1,2,]")) // Actual: [1, 2] Expected: [1, 2, null]
    println(doTest("[1,,2]")) // Actual: [1, 2] Expected: [1, null, 2]
    println(doTest("[,1,2]")) // Actual: [1, 2] Expected: [null, 1, 2]
}

fun doTest(input: String): List<Int?> {
    val lexer = TestLexer(CharStreams.fromString(input))
    val tokens = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    val parser = TestParser(tokens)
    return Visitor.visit(parser.list())
}

object Visitor : TestBaseVisitor<List<Int?>>() {
    override fun visitList(ctx: TestParser.ListContext): List<Int?> =
            ctx.elems.map { s -> s.text.toIntOrNull() }
}
```

This results in, a list like `[1,2]` for all three expressions. What changes can I make to be able to distinguish these inputs?

Comment: The parse tree should also contain the commas, hence when you encounter a leading comma you know there's a missing leading value. Similar for a trailing comma. And in the middle for multiple consequitive commas you know there are missing values too. Sounds pretty trivial.

Comment: Is there any way for me to get that in `ctx.elems` without having to do the transformation myself?

Comment: What transformation? You have to walk over the element list anyway. Only very few extra processing is necessary. Don't load your grammar with such special behavior and try to create a bite-sized tree for you. This will only create other problems keeping you away from the easy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do ...

Grammar:

```
grammar Test;

list : '[' leading_item? item*     ']';

leading_item: 
    NUMBER
;

item:
    COMMA | COMMA NUMBER
;

NUMBER:
    '0' | ('1'..'9')('0'..'9')*
;

COMMA:
    ','
;
```

Extend the base visitor provided by antlr:

```
public class TestVisitor extends TestBaseVisitor<ArrayList<String>> {
    @Override
    public ArrayList<String> visitList(ListContext ctx) {
        ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();

        if(ctx.leading_item() !=  null) {
            ret.add(ctx.leading_item().NUMBER().getText());
        }

        if(ctx.item() != null) {
            for(ItemContext itemCtx : ctx.item()) {
                if(itemCtx.NUMBER() != null) {
                    ret.add(itemCtx.NUMBER().getText());
                }
                else {
                    ret.add("");
                }
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Call it

```
    TestLexer lexer = new TestLexer(charStream);
    TokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    TestParser parser = new TestParser(tokens);
    ParseTree tree = parser.list();

    TestVisitor visitor = new TestVisitor();
    ArrayList<String> list = visitor.visit(tree);
```

Note:

You have to keep in mind that ANTLR is 'only' providing an easy way to walk trough the grammar. The semantic of list, comma, number is irrelevant for the parser. So when you speak of Missing Elements, it's out of the parser's league.